# Why say the module isn`t not found?

Tags: class, module, frameworks, omnet++, inet

I'm trying access the hostA.cc but it is giving me the follow error:

*Class "hostA" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel() -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) WirelessA (id=1), during network setup*

Following my code .ned and .cc:

```
@license(LGPL);

import inet.applications.pingapp.PingApp;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.ipv4.IIpv4;
import inet.node.inet.INetworkNode;
import inet.visualizer.common.InfoVisualizer;
import inet.visualizer.contract.IIntegratedVisualizer;
import inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;

network WirelessA
{
    parameters:
        @display("bgb=740.44,558.54;bgg=100,1,grey95");
        @figure[title](type=label; pos=0,-1; anchor=sw; color=darkblue);
        @figure[rcvdPkText](type=indicatorText; pos=380,20; anchor=w; font=,18; textFormat="packets received time: %g"; initialValue=0);
        @statistic[packetSent](source=hostA.app[0].packetSent; record=figure(count); targetFigure=rcvdPkText);



    submodules:

        visualizer: <default("IntegratedCanvasVisualizer")> like IIntegratedVisualizer if hasVisualizer() {
            @display("p=580,125");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=580,200");
        }
        radioMedium: <default("UnitDiskRadioMedium")> like IRadioMedium {

            @display("p=580,275");
        }

        hostA: <default("hostA")> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=286.00,333.00");
        }
        hostB: <default("WirelessHost")> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=495.00,340.00");
        }
        hostR1: <default("WirelessHost")> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=195.81,105.93;is=s");
        }
        hostR2: <default("WirelessHost")> like INetworkNode {
            @display("p=22.47,21.40");
            @networkNode;
        }

}
```

```
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;

module hostA extends StandardHost like interface{
     parameters:
        numWlanInterfaces = default(1);
        @class(hostA);
        @display("i=device/wifilaptop");
}
```

.cc

```
class hostA : public cSimpleModule{
public:

    hostA();

protected:
    virtual void initialize();
};
Define_Module(hostA);



void hostA::initialize(){
    printf("teste");
    EV<< "TESTE";
}
```